# Button.Parent is Null, when Called in the Constructor

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I am using Windows Forms, and .NET Framework v3.5.

I inherited the System.Windows.Forms.Button class,
and in the inheritor, I wrote some code in the Ctor.

In that code, I need to call `this.Parent`,
yet altho `this` exists, `this.Parent` returns null when called in the Button's Ctor.

Since a Control does not have a `Load event` like a Form,
I will need another solution that will enable me to get the Button's Parent, after the button was created (and was added to its parent Form)

What can I use for achieving this?

Comment: It depends to the requirements. What's your requirement exactly? Also `Parent` is the parent control which is not necessarily a form.

Comment: If you share the requirements and describe what you are trying to do, then you may receive some other good suggestions which may fit more with the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to your own [`ParentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event (or, better yet, override the [`OnParentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onparentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which saves you from having to set up the event subscription)

Comment: Thank you Damien. I will use it. But for general knowledge, is there anything similar to the `Load event`, in a Control? Some Event/Method that we can use, that happens after the Ctor, and inwhich all things are accessible?

Comment: @spaceman - there are several  `OnParentXxx` methods that you may consider overriding which may be close to what you're asking for. Just realise that, in the general case, there's no way for any control to determine "everything is now set up" since we can build dynamic UIs.

Comment: Thank you Damien and Lasse! Both your answers (`ParentChanged` and `HandleCreated`) work perfect, I will use them from now on.